# How to style custom dialog to look like system one?

Tags: android, dialog, themes

Is it possible to apply styles or themes to views in custom Android dialog, such that they will resemble the original system dialog look? I'm aware, that this may be hard in terms of placing items, but at least I'd like to match fonts, colors, font sizes etc.

Comment: can I know what you are using for your custom dialog View..? either activity / dialog, which one..?

Comment: @RajeshVijayakumar I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. I'm deriving from Dialog and the dialog will be used within some Activities.

Comment: Maybe not what you need/want, but AlertDialog has a lot of functionality including adding some custom views.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Dialog offerDialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
            openOfferDialog(offerDialog);
```